# How is it possible that old Joe was killed by young Joe, but he appears again?

Tags: plot-explanation, looper

There are 3 possibilities shown in movie. In one scenario, old Joe is killed as soon as he appears in the field. In 2nd scenario, he turns his back and survives. In 3rd, things change as young Joe kills himself.

I'm confused about 1st and 2nd scenarios. I mean when he was killed in 1st scenario, how come he came *again* to past from future?

Was it the concept of time travel that once your old self is killed (i.e., closed loop), he becomes alive again in future and possibly that's how he managed to go back into past again?

**If yes:**

Does it mean, it will keep happening again and again as long as young Joe keeps killing his old Joe? If yes, it quite doesn't make sense, because this way, the old Joe will never die in future unless natural death causes.

Comment: https://screenrant.com/looper-ending-explanation-time-travel-spoilers/ , etc.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30796/is-there-really-an-infinite-loop-in-looper , https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15539/crossing-your-own-timeline-changing-the-future-how-does-that-work , https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/4473/what-happened-to-change-joes-timeline , https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/4468/how-did-the-timeline-work

Comment: @Luciano sorry no. I can't relate/understand how those answers can be related to my queries.

Comment: check that and the other questions linked by BCdotWEB, when you understand the timeline you'll see the answer to your question. Joe doesn't "become alive again". He dies old (twice), he has to grow older so he can travel back. It's the same person.

Comment: Also "Joe will never die in future": yep, since he travels to the past where he then dies...

Comment: @Luciano oh, I misunderstood it. You're right he "doesn't become alive again", it's the young Joe who turns old right?

Comment: @Luciano also your 2nd comment about "he'll never die in future", does it conclude that Joe will actually have max age around 30s (i mean the younger) and not older than that? because he killed himself and hence he can never grow and hence the Old Joe won't even exist.